# Show value as % of column total in pandas pivot

Tags: python, pandas, pivot

I am doing a pivot of values in pandas as follows-

```
ddp=pd.pivot_table(df, values = 'Loan.ID', index=['DPD2'], columns = 'PaymentPeriod',aggfunc='count').reset_index()
```

But instead of getting count of Loan.ID I want the count of Loan.ID divided by the column total for each column.
For example instead of getting values like below (I dont have the grand total row as shown in the image)-

[image]

I want the percentage as below.

[image]

How to do this in pandas.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ifvalues are not numeric, first cast to floats or convert non parseable to `NaN`s:

```
ddp = ddp.astype(float)
#alternative 
#ddp = ddp.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
```

Then use `sum` for `Grand Total` last row:

```
ddp = pd.DataFrame({'2017-06': [186, 104, 2], '2017-07': [294,98,10]})
ddp.loc['Grand Total'] = ddp.sum()
print (ddp)
             2017-06  2017-07
0                186      294
1                104       98
2                  2       10
Grand Total      292      402
```

And divide all Data by last row by [`DataFrame.div`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.div.html), multiple by `100` and add percentage:

```
df = ddp.div(ddp.iloc[-1]).mul(100).round(2).astype(str) + '%'
print(df)
            2017-06 2017-07
0             63.7%  73.13%
1            35.62%  24.38%
2             0.68%   2.49%
Grand Total  100.0%  100.0%
```

Of if need floats with double `00`:

```
df = ddp.div(ddp.iloc[-1]).mul(100).round(2).applymap("{:10.02f}%".format)
print(df)
                 2017-06      2017-07
0                 63.70%       73.13%
1                 35.62%       24.38%
2                  0.68%        2.49%
Grand Total      100.00%      100.00%
```

Comment: Hi, I am getting this error-TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'str',

Comment: @NishaPandey - completely changed solution.

Comment: Thanks jezrae,Will try the solution but I dont have the  grand total row as shown in the image,Will this solution work without it..?

Comment: @NishaPandey - Added sample data, need `ddp.loc['Grand Total'] = ddp.sum()` after casting to floats.

Answer (score 0):

you can also try below code for column specific format change by `style.format`:

```
df =df.style.format({'Column1':'{:,.0%}'.format,'Column2':'{:,.1%}'.format,})
```

you need to include specific column name instead of 'Column' label in the above code.

let me know if this code work for you.